# I want to know usage of 's (with apostrophe) in the example given below

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, possessives

According to some grammar, *'s* is used for human.

I know some of the usages here:

- > My uncle's son Faizan goes to Bombay Cambridge School every day.

  Used as ‘of’ for human possession.
- > It’s been ages since her mother met me.

  Used as an auxiliary verb has.

**We are checking:**

- **Availability of Jio Ture5G network in your usage-areas most of the times**
- **Your handset's compatibility with Jio True 5G**
- **On success, your invitation for Jio Welcome Offer will be on the way soon.**

The confusion is in this example: “*your handset's compatibility....*”
Should I consider 's ‘has’ as a verb ("*your handset has...*"), or as the *of* in that example, or is that sentence incorrect?

I suspect “*your handset’s compatibility...*” is incorrect; what do you think?

Comment: Hi, Faheem - **'s** for possession doesn't have to be for humans only.  It can be for anything, like "the computer **'s** keyboard".  Did you see in a grammar book that it was only for humans?

Comment: Handset's compatability is correct.  It is possessive.  There is no problem with inanimate possession using apostrophe s.

Comment: My dog's tail, my car's engine, a tree's branches, the earth's people.

Comment: Thanks, I agree! I love the words "my dog’s tail,".  How beautiful! 

Comment: Or you can have **my tale's dog**.

Comment: @RonaldSole - is it shaggy?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Some more than others: White Fang, Marley, Lassie, Toto and Mello (who's really shaggy - and mine)

Comment: Whether or not an inanimate noun (one that doesn't represent a living thing) can take a possessive 's is something that grammar experts argue about - see [this](https://style.mla.org/inanimate-nouns-and-possession/).

Answer (score 1):

The construction 's forms what is called a genative, or more exactly one type og genitive. This can  be used to show possession, as with

> My uncle's house is green.

Presumably the uncle owns, or at least occupies, the house. But it can also be used to show association, as in:

> My uncle's friend is Sylvia.

We may safely say that the uncle does not own or posses Sylvia, but he is associated with her. The line between possession and association is often not clear. When an 's construction is used with an inanimate object, it may be clearer to think of it as indicating association rather than possession. This is perhaps even ore true of an abstract object. The following are all valid sentences, and are quite natural.

> - The computer's keyboard is broken.
> - The Theory's origin is unclear.
> - The country's enemy was clever.
> - The water's taste was salty.
> - The mountain's eastern neighbor is not as tall.
> - The novel's sequel sold poorly.
> - The Impressionists' predecessors were realists.

Some grammarains objrct to a possesive of an inanamate object, or do so in some cases. But such constructions are widely used, including by respected authors. They cannot realistically be called errors in grammar. Ass Winston Churchill is supposed to have said regarding another grammatical "rule":

> That is the sort of silliness up with which I will not put.

By the was "it's" is a contraction of "it is", and is not a posesive nor a genative of any sort. The possessive of "it" is "its", just as the possessive of "he" is "his".